# Ternary operator is not showing correct result in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

if totalRecords don't have the number then it should show result "We found No Duplicate Records for lead but it is showing nothing even totalRecords attribute value is there or not

```
<p>We found {!v.totalRecords.size()>0?'{!v.totalRecords}':'No'} duplicates Records for Lead(s) <br/>
```

Comment: Have you tried **v.totalRecords** instead of **'{!v.totalRecords}'** ?

Comment: yes, but it haven't worked

Answer (score 2):

I doubt `.size()` is a valid way to check. However `.length` would work.

```
{!v.list.length > 0 ?   'Duplicate records found!' :'No duplicate record'}
```

This way you'd be getting correct results.
We do have another great alternative to check a empty list is `not(empty()` which can be implemented like,

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.list))}">
        {!v.list.length} duplicates found
        <aura:set attribute="else">
           No duplicates found!
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
```

Comment: You're right https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm